# A problem on Vector Space

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V=M(10,R)$. $A$ is an element of $V$. Let me take the set $S=\{I, A, A^2, A^3,\ldots, A^{100}\}$. Prove that, dimension of $L(S)\leq 10$.

Comment: What is L(S)???

Comment: @Batman Maybe the span of $S$?

Comment: Please provide your thoughts and working so we can help you easier. This website is not a homework-doing-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming L(S) is the linear span of S.

By the Cayley Hamilton Theorem, every matrix satistifes its characteristic equation. That is, if $p(\lambda) = det(\lambda I -A)$ for a matrix $A$, then $P(A) = 0$ when you replace $\lambda^i$ with $A^i$ in the expression for $p(\lambda)$. Note that $\lambda$ is a $n$-th degree polynomial for a n x n matrix (so $P(A)$ would be a linear combination of  $A^n,A^{n-1},\ldots, A^1, A^0 = I$).

Cayley Hamilton implies that if you have a 10-dimensional matrix $A$, you can find a linear combination of $I=A^0,\ldots,A^9, A^{10}$ such that it is zero. So, you can write every integer power of $A$ greater than 9 in terms of $I, A, A^2, \ldots, A^9$ so the dimension of $L(S)$ is at most 10.